# Where do port knocking services listen for incoming knocks?

Tags: networking, iptables, port, monitoring

I'm trying to understand how a port-knocking daemon is able to monitor for knocks, independent of the firewall rules (e.g. accept/drop/reject packets).

I've installed [knockd](http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock), which listens for lets say the knock sequence 42,42,42. These are dropped by my `iptables` firewall but `knockd` is able to recognize the traffic and performs the defined action. On the website it states "knockd listens at the link-layer level".

How and where does `knockd` monitor for knocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

knockd links against libpcap so that it can watch traffic on the wire similarly to any other sniffer like tcpdump or wireshark. This happens at level before iptables DROP rules (which integrate with the IP stack) are able to apply. This is why knockd can see the incoming traffic, and if you ran tcpdump instead it would also be able to see the traffic.

However, if you are going to run something that requires libpcap, then you might want something that offers stronger security properties that simple knock sequences. Single Packet Authorization accomplishes this.